# Why won't JBoss Resteasy maven dependency work?

Tags: maven, jboss, jax-rs, resteasy

I added

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
    <artifactId>resteasy-jaxrs-all</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.1.GA</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

and I'm using

```
<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>jboss</id>
        <url>http://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/groups/public</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>
```

When I try to build, I get the following error. What am I doing wrong?

> [ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project tapvox-api: Could not resolve dependencies for project com.myproject.api:myproject-api:war:1.0-SNAPSHOT: Could not find artifact org.jboss.resteasy:resteasy-jaxrs-all:jar:2.2.1.GA in jboss (http://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/groups/public) -> [Help 1]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The dependency that you are trying to download does not have any jars or transitive dependencies. Since the default type is jar, then this will fail. If you put

```
<type>pom</type>
```

in your dependency, then you get the only artifact that this dependency has to offer. See [pom](https://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/groups/public/org/jboss/resteasy/resteasy-jaxrs-all/2.2.1.GA/resteasy-jaxrs-all-2.2.1.GA.pom)

I guess that you are trying to fetch the wrong dependency.

Comment: Yup thanks. I wanted to get resteasy-jaxrs ... I guess after looking at the screen for hours resteasy-jaxrs-all looked the same X(

Answer (score 2):

You have to specify a dependency type.  Change your dependency to look like this:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
    <artifactId>resteasy-jaxrs-all</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.1.GA</version>
    <type>pom</type>                             <<<<<
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```