# Adding swagger to a RestEasy servlet under JBoss - missing dependency and conflicting URI template

Tags: maven, jboss, swagger, resteasy

I have been struggling with converting my servlet working under RestEasy and JBoss to include a Swagger description.  I have tried making some dependencies of scope provided, tried making them of type pom, tried changing the context-param's in the web.xml, etc. I have considered [this post ][1] and [this post] (which seemed a great match) [2] but seem to be going backwards so please help me address:

```
  SEVERE: Missing dependency for constructor public org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.providers.JaxrsServerFormUrlEncodedProvider(boolean) at parameter index 0
  SEVERE: Missing dependency for constructor public org.jboss.resteasy.core.AsynchronousDispatcher(org.jboss.resteasy.spi.ResteasyProviderFactory) at parameter index 0
  SEVERE: Conflicting URI templates. The URI template /api-docs for root resource class com.wordnik.swagger.jaxrs.listing.ApiListingResourceJSON and the URI template /api-docs transform to the same regular expression /api\-docs(/.*)?
```

The relevant part of my pom.xml seems to be (with irrelevant dependencies removed):

```
    <properties>
...     <jackson.version>2.10.0</jackson.version>           
        <version.org.slf4j>1.7.26</version.org.slf4j>
        <swagger-version>1.3.0</swagger-version>        
        <jax-rs-version>1.1.1</jax-rs-version>
        <json4s-jackson-version>3.2.4</json4s-jackson-version>
        <json4s-core-version>3.0.0</json4s-core-version>
        <fasterxml-json-version>2.2.2</fasterxml-json-version>
        <reflections-version>0.9.9-RC1</reflections-version>
        <javassist-version>3.16.1-GA</javassist-version>
        <paranamer-version>2.5.2</paranamer-version>
        <scannotation-version>1.0.3</scannotation-version>
        <servlet-api-version>2.5</servlet-api-version>
    </properties>
...
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.wordnik</groupId>
            <artifactId>swagger-jaxrs_2.10</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.5</version>
        </dependency>       
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax</groupId>
            <artifactId>javaee-web-api</artifactId>
            <version>6.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.thetransactioncompany</groupId>
            <artifactId>cors-filter</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.1</version>
        </dependency>
       <dependency>
            <groupId>com.wordnik</groupId>
            <artifactId>swagger-servlet_2.10</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.0</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>dom4j</artifactId>
                    <groupId>dom4j</groupId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
            <type>jar</type>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-jaxrs</artifactId>
            <version>1.9.13</version> 
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.ws.rs</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsr311-api</artifactId>
            <version>${jax-rs-version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.json4s</groupId>
            <artifactId>json4s-jackson_2.9.1-1</artifactId>
            <version>${json4s-jackson-version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.json4s</groupId>
            <artifactId>json4s-core_2.9.2</artifactId>
            <version>${json4s-core-version}</version>
        </dependency>        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.thoughtworks.paranamer</groupId>
            <artifactId>paranamer</artifactId>
            <version>${paranamer-version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.scala-lang</groupId>
            <artifactId>scala-library</artifactId>
            <version>2.12.15</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.reflections</groupId>
            <artifactId>reflections</artifactId>
            <version>${reflections-version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>${servlet-api-version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.javassist</groupId>
            <artifactId>javassist</artifactId>
            <version>${javassist-version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.scannotation</groupId>
            <artifactId>scannotation</artifactId>
            <version>${scannotation-version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.wordnik</groupId>
            <artifactId>swagger-jersey-jaxrs_2.9.1</artifactId>
            <version>${swagger-version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.wordnik</groupId>
            <artifactId>swagger-annotations_2.9.1</artifactId>
            <version>${swagger-version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.wordnik</groupId>
            <artifactId>swagger-core_2.9.1</artifactId>
            <version>${swagger-version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.wordnik</groupId>
            <artifactId>swagger-jaxrs_2.9.1</artifactId>
            <version>${swagger-version}</version>
        </dependency>   
      <dependency>
                <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
                <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
                <version>${jackson.version}</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
            <version>${jackson.version}</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
            <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
            <version>4.5.13</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
          <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
          <artifactId>resteasy-jaxrs-all</artifactId>
          <version>2.2.1.GA</version>
          <type>pom</type>                             
          <scope>provided</scope>
     </dependency>
...
```

The application is trivial:

```
    @Path("pam")
    @Provider
    @Api(value="/pam", description = "Returns data")
    public class PamQueryHandler extends Application {
     
    public PamQueryHandler() {
    }
        
    @ApiOperation(value = "Perform the actual query.", response = Response.class)    
    @GET
    @Path("/query")  
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public Response handleQuery(@ApiParam(value="messageType") @QueryParam("messageType") String message) 
    {
...
    }
```

And a web.xml whose content is almost entirely to accommodate the Swagger description:

```
<web-app>
  <display-name>RESTful Querying of DBs</display-name>
  
  <context-param>
       <param-name>resteasy.wider.request.matching</param-name>
       <param-value>true</param-value>
    </context-param>
    
    <context-param>
        <param-name>javax.ws.rs.core.Application</param-name>
        <param-value>com.goprecise.jbpm.rest.PamQueryHandler</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>resteasy.resources</param-name>
        <param-value>com.wordnik.swagger.jaxrs.listing.ApiListingResourceJSON</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>resteasy.providers</param-name>
        <param-value>
            com.wordnik.swagger.jaxrs.json.JacksonJsonProvider,
            com.wordnik.swagger.jaxrs.listing.ApiDeclarationProvider,
            com.wordnik.swagger.jaxrs.listing.ResourceListingProvider
        </param-value>
    </context-param>    
        
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.ResteasyBootstrap</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>resteasy-servlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher</servlet-class>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>resteasy-servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/query/*</url-pattern>
        <!--url-pattern>/api-docs/*</url-pattern-->
    </servlet-mapping>
        
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>DefaultJaxrsConfig</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>com.wordnik.swagger.jaxrs.config.DefaultJaxrsConfig</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>api.version</param-name>
            <param-value>1.0.0</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>swagger.api.basepath</param-name>
            <param-value>http://localhost:8090/PamQuery</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>2</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
</web-app>

  [1]: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8171342/why-wont-jboss-resteasy-maven-dependency-work
  [2]: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9378106/jboss-7-1-0-error-unable-to-find-a-public-constructor-for-class-org-jboss-rest
```

Comment: This should be provided : <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.ws.rs</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsr311-api</artifactId>
            <version>${jax-rs-version}</version>
        </dependency>

Comment: Tried that - still seeing:  09:29:48,867 SEVERE [com.sun.jersey.spi.inject.Errors] (default task-3) The following errors and warnings have been detected with resource and/or provider classes:
  SEVERE: Missing dependency for constructor public org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.providers.JaxrsServerFormUrlEncodedProvider(boolean) at parameter index 0
  SEVERE: Missing dependency for constructor public org.jboss.resteasy.core.AsynchronousDispatcher(org.jboss.resteasy.spi.ResteasyProviderFactory) at parameter index 0
  SEVERE: Conflicting URI templates. The URI template /api-docs for root resource cl

Comment: It looks like you're mixing RESTEasy and Jersey which are different Jakarta RESTful Web Services implementations. What version of WildFly are you targeting?

Comment: @JamesR.Perkins JBoss EAP 7.3.0.GA (WildFly Core 10.1.2.Final-redhat-00001)
The service code is in RestEasy so I would like the web.xml and pom.xml to reflect RestEasy.  I took my Swagger code from an example that I will add the URL of to this post later

Comment: The second comment indicates an error coming from Jersey and there is a dependency on `swagger-jersey-jaxrs_2.9.1`. I'm not a Swagger expert, but that could be expecting Jersey being used or bring Jersey in transitively. Also that version of RESTEasy is not in 7.3.0.GA. It will be a 3.x based version.